# Xaml error message

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm getting error message just in the beginning of my XAML tagging section as

Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '8' and line position '9'.

```
<Window x:Class="prj.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:prj"
    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:prj.Controls"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    Height="850" Width="1000">
```

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Amit

Comment: Can you post stacktrace or innerexception

Comment: if you are using any staticresource in your xaml then make sure it is available.

Answer (score 0):

This error may cause by the following reason:
For static resource, you should define it before reference to it (dynamic resource doesn't have this limitation).
for details,see:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/f76fdf5d-a9cd-4f42-b2a0-ad560744a39f

**Maybe it's not useful,but check you code carefully first.**

Comment: I saw that forum before I submit the question but it did not help. As you see in the beginning of Xaml I have no used anything thing that requires reference ... I even removed those two clr-namespace lines and yet I'm receiving the error message. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The line and column numbers are not relevant here. In this type of exception they are probably moot.

Dig into inner exceptions and look for the key that it cannot find. Then search for that key in the entire solution to see where it gets used. For each usage, make sure that the resource is available.

Usually, this happens when there's one user control (UC1) that has a resource which is used in the body of UC1. Then, another developer copies part of UC1 to UC2 without copying the resource. When UC2 is used in a window, this type of cryptic message shows.

Comment: right I'm working on a pre-written code and had missed it. Thank you it was a good help.

Comment: Glad that it helped. Please mark one of the replies as an answer to help other people in future searches.

Answer (score 0):

The line number and position are probably referencing the `InitializeComponent()` method from the code behind. I'd go with most suggestions. Make sure your static resource is available before you use it.

Are you using a static reference anywhere in that XAML file? If so, find the dictionary it is defined in and make sure it is loaded before the XAML file. The easiest way to do this is by adding the resource dictionary to your applications [merged dictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178.aspx). You can refresh your knowledge of static resources [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750950.aspx).

Comment: Yes in fact problem was in application dictionary. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same thing but the problem I had was because I defined  a `DataTemplate` for a `ListBox` in the UserControl's Resources section but, being fairly new to WPF, I included a `DataType=”ListBoxItem”`.

Well, that caused the problem because the `DataType` was unnecessary. Taking that away fixed my issue.